# Floor and ceiling opposite property

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

For $x\in \mathbb{R}$ let's define $[x]$ as:
$$
[x] = max \{ k\in \mathbb{Z}: k\leq x \}
$$
and $[x]^{*}$ as:
$$
[x]^{*} = min \{ k\in \mathbb{Z}: k\geq x \}.
$$
Show that:
$$
[x]^{*} = -[-x].
$$

So far I have managed to notice that:
$$
[x]^{*} -1 \leq x < [x]^{*}
$$
so:
$$
-[x]^{*} \leq -x < 1- [x]^{*}
$$
I believe that it might be the right direction here, but I have a problem to manipulate it further to get the $-[-x]$ form.

Comment: Your last inequality implies $[-x]=-[x]^{*}$ so you are done basically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for a subset of integers $A$ the following holds
$$\min A=-\max\{-x:x\in A\}$$
Therefore
$$[x]^*=-\max\{-k:k\ge x\}\cap\mathbb Z=-\max\{-k:-k\le -x\}\cap\mathbb Z\\
=-\max\{k:k\le -x\}\cap\mathbb Z=-[-x]$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, when in trouble set variables.

If $x \in \mathbb Z$ then $x = \lfloor x \rfloor = \lceil x \rceil$[*] and the result is trivial.

Otherwise

Let $\lfloor x \rfloor = k$.  So $k < x < k + 1$.[**]

So $\lceil x \rceil = k + 1$.

$-k - 1 < - x < -k$

So $\lfloor -x \rfloor = -k -1$

An $\lceil -x \rceil = -k$.

====

[* and **] We probably shouldn't take these for granted but they're easy though tedious to prove via the archimedian property and the transitivity of order.